Why Can't Data Members Be Exported To A DLL?
As far as I understand, the point of __declspec(dllexport) is to be an instruction during DLL compilation to export enough information to the LIB that goes with the DLL to allow specifically member methods in the DLL to be called in linkers of the DLL by their un-mangled name. If one tries to call a member method defined as public in a header included with the DLL but that member method is not exported then the the project that links the DLL will itself fail at the link stage of building due to unresolved external symbols.
That's all well and good for member methods, but why are the rules completely different for data members? Data members declared as public in a header included with a DLL can be accessed by their un-mangled name in the projects that link the DLL even though as far as I understand the name of the data member would become mangled by the DLL compilation process. I don't quite know the definition of a symbol beyond 'something in the source code', so is it as simple as member methods are symbols and data members aren't symbols so data members don't get their names mangled for whatever reason?

Data members can't be overloaded like functions and operators can be.  Thus there is no need to mangle their names.

Ah okay, that makes sense, if that were an actual answer response to the question rather than a comment I'd approve it as the answer. Thank you anyway!

Non-static data members are not accessed by name; the linker is not involved in accessing them. The object occupies a chunk of memory (that this points to), and a given data member is at some well-known, hard-coded offset within this memory. Consider: there is a distinct set of non-static data members, at distinct addresses, for each instance of the class you create.  They can't possibly be located at some address known at link time, only at run time. In contrast, global variables and static data members are in fact linked, and can in fact be exported from a DLL.

Also, __declspec(dllexport) does nothing to "un-mangle" a function name.  extern "C" does that.  If you export a C++ function, it will export the mangled name.

it not different
